# Upload new image through amazon sp api or S3 storage to attach it to new product

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am using the sp api from amazon , when I add an image with a non S3 url it gets an error and needs the image to be hosted on amazon servers , so I need to add a new image to attach it to the product nd have the url to use it when sending the product with the sp listings api posting it

I found documentation on how to upload the image through the S3 , i made an api endpoint with Put method but I reached a dead end

So is there a way to upload the image as a new one programmatically through the apis